# What does "power and scope" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I can only guess that author means affecting and, maybe, detailed books. Thank you very much for help.

> He was a padrone of language like no other. His newspaper articles
> were specific, clear, and truthful; his headlines plain and direct. He
> went on to write glorious books **of power and scope**.

Adriana Trigiani "The Shoemaker's Wife"

Comment: Have you looked at those words in a good dictionary, like Cambridge? If so, what did you not understand?

Comment: I did. Here's an explanation of scope. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scope And  yes, I still do not understand what is the book of scope :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we say a thing is **of a noun** where the *noun* is the name of a quality or attribute, we mean that the thing **has a lot of that quality**.

A person **of strength** is a person who **has much strength**.

A book **of power** is a book which **has much power** (to impress, teach, inform, convince, etc).

A book **of scope** is a book which **has much scope** - i.e. a wide 'range of things that it deals with' (subject matter).

Comment: Yes, same as: books with power and scope. I never ever understand these types of questions.I recknon the idea is the same in the OP's language.

Comment: Question was about "scope" meaning  in this context, maybe the formulation was wrong.